# Vim Regex - How to invert a regex which matches multiple lines?

Tags: regex, vim, multiline, regex-negation, inverse

My goal is the regex to match everything but
the multi-line matches from the original regex.

This is the regex which I'm trying to invert:

`\vselect\_.{-};`

It matches correctly on the bellow sample code. 
The sql statements are included and not the capitalized text.

```
THIS TEXT IS WHAT I WANT TO
MATCH ONCE THE ABOVE
REGEX IS CORRECTLY INVERTED.

select *
from foo
where bar;

THIS TEXT IS WHAT I WANT TO
MATCH ONCE THE ABOVE
REGEX IS CORRECTLY INVERTED.

select *
from bar
where foo;

THIS TEXT IS WHAT I WANT TO
MATCH ONCE THE ABOVE
REGEX IS CORRECTLY INVERTED.
```

Following the vim documentation on how to do
invert (negate) a regex, this is what I come up with:

`\v^(select\_.{-};)@!.*`

This regex matches on everything but on the first lines
from the sql statements. I want all lines from the
sql statements to be excluded and not just the first lines.

I also tried not to use the `\v` very magic directive and
escaped everything, but no luck, getting the same result.

What am I doing wrong? 
Also if anyone can think of another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do would be great, the answer does not have to follow the way I'm trying it.

Comment: What is you final goal? Replace or highlight? Note that if you can use a [Perl regex in Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Perl_compatible_regular_expressions), you could use [a Perl regex for this](https://regex101.com/r/uB7uN7/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, looking at the sample code, my final goal is the regex to match everything but the sql statements.

Comment: @gsavovski can we use the blank lines? can the "TEXT" contain `;` ? Can sql stmts contain empty lines? Is it ok for you, if we remove all sqls from the buffer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I misunderstood you. My final goal is to highlight. It is functionality I need for a notes taking plugin I'm working on.

Comment: I have a .NET regex for this. I will try to convert it to VIM.

Comment: @Kent, good points. The sql stmts can possibly have empty lines and the non-inverted regex will still work. The "TEXT" can possibly have empty lines and `;`, but very unlikely to end with `;`.  I need nothing to be removed.

Comment: @gsavovski then pls tell me, if you were a machine, how can you tell which part is TEXT and which part is not. don't forget, the sql statements are texts too.  There must be some key  difference that we can make use of to check.  E.g. Texts are always upper cases whereas sqls must have lower letters?

Comment: and if sql can have empty lines, you cannot rely on "select", since there could be sub-queries with empty line. and the TEXT could have leading "select" as well.... I think I cannot answer the question since the requirement is not clear..

Comment: @Kent, The TEXT can never start with a leading `select` and end with a `;`. Also there will never be a sql statement included in the TEXT.

Comment: Try `\(^|select\_.{-};\)\@<=[^s]*(s\(elect\_.{-};\)\@![^s]*)*\($|select\_.{-};\)\@=` and if it does not work, try to escape the `|` (not sure if it should be escaped or not). The .NET regex is `(?s)(?<=^|select.*?;)[^s]*(?:s(?!elect.*?;)[^s]*)*(?=$|select.*?;)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, The regex does not work. Yep `|` had to be escaped when not in very magic mode.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the regex from your first comment [a Perl regex for](https://regex101.com/r/uB7uN7/1) works perfectly, even if you have "TEXT" before and after. I will try to figure out how to translate that to vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking it over, I think I got what you meant...

This line should work for you:

```
\v;\n\n\zs\_.{-}\ze\n\_^select
```

#### Update according to the comment:

And this vimregex works if you have leading/ending TEXT blocks:

```
\v(;\n\n\zs\_.{-}|%^(select)@!\_.{-})\ze(\n\_^select|\n?%$)
```

Comment: Definitely progress, Thanks. Your regex works on the sample code from the question. But looks like it works only if the "TEXT" is between sql statements. It should also work if the "TEXT" appears before and after the sql statements. There also could be consecutive sql statements. For simplicity I created the initial sample code as such, now I updated the sample code in the question.

Comment: Just as a note, the regex from the first comment from  
@WiktorStribiżew [a Perl regex for](https://regex101.com/r/uB7uN7/1) , works for the cases above too. Just how to translate that to vim regex?

Comment: @gsavovski I was on my way home just now. Now I updated my answer according to your comment. It should match all three blocks.

Comment: Amazing, I marked your answer. I've been trying to figure this one for some time now. I also must admit that I don't get your solution, I have never used the \zs and \ze. If you get a chance please explain your approach with some detail. Also mention like why would you start with `;` and what about those double `\n`.

Comment: I'm working on a notes plugin which should support multiple file types in the same file. Currently my custom notes type, R and sql. The idea is without any additional markup the plugin to recognize what is text(notes), what is code and treat them differently. For the sample your regex works perfectly, but when I tried it on my complicated long files I see it doesn't work for some cases. I will figure those cases out once I understand your solution.

Thanks, again for your help!

Comment: `\n\n` is empty line. there is `(;...|%^...)` so it is OR.  `\zs \ze` are very handy, `:h \zs` for details. `@!` is negative look ahead. `:h @!` for details. also `:h %^  :h %$` @gsavovski

Comment: Yep, totally get it. I kept trying to think about your solution as inversion of a match. For empty line I usually use `^$`. Also the \zs and \ze directives are great. Thanks, @Kent.